# How do I add a cell value from a different worksheet in a string?

Tags: excel, vba

For example:

DestinationWorksheetCell: The <SourceWorksheetCell:StoryNamename> of the story has three main characters: <SourceWorksheetCell:name1>, <SourceWorksheetCell:name2>, and <SourceWorksheetCell:name3>

I have my data source in the same workbook but different worksheet, and each row is a record so I cannot loop through them. is there a way to do concatenate the info cells in a paragraph that is destined to one cell and loop through the records in the source worksheet?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific, please? Post a data sample. Why would you want to loop if you just want to concatenate three cell values? Do you also need to FIND the cells to concatenate? If so, what are the criteria for finding them? i.e., why can't you just use something like `=Sheet1!A1 & Sheet2!B4 & Sheet3!Z8` ??

Answer (score 1):

It isn't objectively true that you can't loop through rows because they contain records.  Unfortunately, your question contains no hint as to what purpose you considered looping for. Is it related to finding the parts of the names you wish to concatenate?

There are many ways to concatenate text, regardless of where the text comes from (cells, partial cells, keyboard, variables, constructs). Here is one.

```
Private Sub Try()

    Dim MyName(1 To 3)  As String                   ' declare an array of 3 elements
    
    MyName(1) = Sheet2.Range("A3").Value            ' assign a value to element #1
    MyName(2) = Sheet2.Range("B5").Value            ' assign a value to element #2
    MyName(3) = Sheet2.Range("C9").Value            ' assign a value to element #3
    
    ' assign the concatenated string to the target cell
    Sheet1.Cells(2, "A").Value = Join(MyName, " ")
End Sub
```

To try this code, take a blank workbook with `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` in it. Write something in cells A3, B5 and C9 of Sheet2. Then run the code and see the result on Sheet1!A2.

Comment: Thank you @Variatus this piece of code is very helpful. and yes, I have my data source and each row is a record, so while I'm calling the values in my destination worksheet I want to loop through the values assigned within the text that come from my source worksheet. hopefully this is clear, but let me know if it needs more details.

Comment: I don't understand "loop through the values assigned within the text". Normally, one would loop through all rows (=records) and look at one or more columns to find one or more records that match given criteria. Presumably, you want to loop through records in your `SourceWorksheet`. Please amend your question to clarify what you want to look for and which column(s) to find it in. Is it one search with 3 criteria? Or is it 3 searches with different criteria? Are you having a number and want to retrieve text? Having one text and want another? Is `StoryNameName` a named range?